# Entity Framework Database.Migrate() does not update the database

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-migrations

I'm using PostgreSql in .NET 6 and I want it to migrate automatically when it's up. I used the code below for this.

```
var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

// migrate any database changes on startup (includes initial db creation)
using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
{
    var dataContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<PostgreDbContext>();
    dataContext.Database.Migrate();
}
```

This code creates if the database does not exist. But when I add or remove a column to one of the tables, it doesn't update when it works again.

When I try the `add-migration` and `update-database` commands from the console, I see that the changes I have made are updated in the database.

I don't understand why it is not updated in code with Entity Framework?

Comment: `Database.Migrate` runs just unapply migrations. whatever  you do related with database, must do add-migration.

Comment: Is there a way to do this in code?

Answer (score 0):

Can you add this extensions method to your project.

```
public static IHost MigrateDatabase(this IHost host)
{
    if (!host.Services.GetService<IWebHostEnvironment>().IsDevelopment())
    {
        using var scope = host.Services.CreateScope();
        using var appContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<DataListContext>();
        var logger = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ILogger<DataListContext>>();
        try
        {
            logger.LogInformation("Migrating database...");
            appContext.Database.Migrate();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.LogError(ex, "An error occurred while migrating the database");
        }
    }

    return host;
}
```

use this way.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    CreateHostBuilder(args)
        .Build()
        .MigrateDatabase()
        .Run();
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work.

Comment: Can you remove it and try that way?
if (!host.Services.GetService<IWebHostEnvironment>().IsDevelopment())